# Discord.js Message.channel.send sends the text as a code with and converts int to strings

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to send a message in discord.js by my bot, I tried to use message.channel.send but it says that the max lengh is 2000 so I've split the message but there's a worse bug happens
the message shows as code, all numbers in it converted to strings
[here how it prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKOkV.png)

all numbers are converted to strings

I tried to split the message but it didn't work
here's the code:

```
if (message.content === "rules") {
   message.channel.send (`**Hello Everyone,
Welcome to Eagle Company, Where you can find all your needs in the freelancing work stage
With our Highly Experienced Sellers, Boosters, and Programmers...
But what are our services ?
1. We provide Programmers for all programming roads.
2. Photo Designers and Graphic Designers.
3. Game boosting and leveling (Smurf accounts). you can check #prices for more details.
4. Marketing for drop shippers and starting websites, stores , etc.
5. Providing projects for freelancers (with a fee).
6. Jobs
===========================================================================================================
First of all, We have some rules that you must follow:
1. We must respect each other.
2. No spamming.
3. Use appropriate language and content.
4. No personal attacks or doxing.
5. Follow Discord's terms of service.
6. Respect server staff and don't mention them for no reason.
7. No unauthorized advertising.
8. NSFW stuff is forbidden and leads to an instant ban.
9. No discord invites.
10. No trolls in Jobs Applications
===========================================================================================================
And now about the store rules:
1. Make sure to check with a broker from the server before making a purchase (for free).
2. Most of the time, our services are provided by freelancers, so if you have problems with them in deals or prices make sure to contact any staff member to solve the sort out
3. You can buy or ask for a service on Discord server by creating a ticket or use our Trusted Selling pages on websites like g2g...Type m.links for websites URLs.
4. Try to be sure before confirming any service in our store, Because we don't do refunds.
============================================================================================================
That was the global rules of the server.
You can find all rules for each server on it's own channel.
and if you need any help, Make a ticket and we will help as fast as possible.

Have fun Everyone.**`)

};
```

Answer (score 1):

That is Discords new formatting by adding spaces before some of your numbers you are unintentionally formatting it, for example text like this:

[image: example]

would turn into this:

[image: example]

A way you could counter this is by escaping the markdown by using `\` or you could substitute the new lines with `\n`

Comment: I can't understand can you explain more or give an example ?